# Setting nameid-format:persistent in SimpleSAML request

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm setting up a single-sign-on (as service provider) via SimpleSAML. After importing the Metadata from the identity provider's XML, the first redirect worked.

However, the login fails with a `sspmod_saml_Error: Requester/InvalidNameIDPolicy: An error occurred.` and the identity provider (idp) tells me that the request should include

```
format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent
```

Instead of

```
format: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient
```

The only thing i found in the SimpleSAML manual refers to the idp configuration ([manual](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/development/simplesamlphp-reference-sp-remote)). However, when I add this to the `metadata/shib13-sp-remote.php` an `metadata/saml20-sp-remote.php` ...

```
$metadata['<same URL as in metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php>'] = array (
        'NameIdFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent'
);
```

... then nothing changes. The request still contains:

```
<samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" AllowCreate="true"/>
```

This is not unexpected, as I am trying to configute the request to the idp, not to an sp. So, in sheer despair, I have also tried setting the `NameIdPolicy` to the same value, and I have also have tried the ...-idp-remote.php files, but (as expected) that did not do the trick, either. And I also tried the ID of my service provider as key for $metadata, but ... well.

Also tried a modification to `metadata/saml20-ipd-hosted.php` as described [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/de/arcgis-online/reference/configure-simplesaml.htm), but that also did have no effect.

It's really fishing in the dark, the SimpleSAML documentation is missing some basic information (where, for example, to put [these parameters](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/saml:sp))... So, I assume that I have the wrong file, the wrong key, or the wrong setting. Any hint is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After search and searching, I found that this behavior is hard-coded in SimpleSAML in `modules/saml/lib/Message.php`

```
    $policy = array(
        'Format'      => $nameIdPolicy_cf->getString('Format', \SAML2\Constants::NAMEID_TRANSIENT),
        'AllowCreate' => $nameIdPolicy_cf->getBoolean('AllowCreate', true),
    );
```

Changing this did not solve the communication problem with the IdP ... so it's probably perfectly okay that it is this way.

Comment: Eventually related: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/issues/771